# Trying to draw multiple circles but both circles connect with a line

Tags: ios, swift

I drew a circle but when I try to add another circle a line connects both circles.

```
import UIKit

class skills: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        var startAngle: Float = Float(2 * M_PI)
        var endAngle: Float = 0.0
        var endAngletwo: Float = 2.0

        // Drawing code
        // Set the radius
        let strokeWidth = 10.0
        let radius = CGFloat((CGFloat(self.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(strokeWidth)) / 20)


        // Get the context
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()



        **// Find the middle of the circle
        let center = CGPointMake(100, 200)

        let inside = CGPointMake(100,400)**

        // Set the stroke color
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)

        // Set the line width
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, CGFloat(strokeWidth))

        // Set the fill color (if you are filling the circle)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)

        // Rotate the angles so that the inputted angles are intuitive like the clock face: the top is 0 (or 2π), the right is π/2, the bottom is π and the left is 3π/2.
        // In essence, this appears like a unit circle rotated π/2 anti clockwise.
        startAngle = startAngle - Float(M_PI_2)
        endAngle = endAngle - Float(M_PI_2)
        endAngletwo = endAngletwo - Float(M_2_PI)

        // Draw the arc around the circle
        CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, CGFloat(radius), CGFloat(startAngle), CGFloat(endAngle), 0)

        CGContextAddArc(context, inside.x, inside.y, CGFloat(radius), CGFloat(startAngle), CGFloat(endAngletwo),0)

        // Draw the arc
        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke) // or kCGPathFillStroke to fill and stroke the circle







    }










}
```

I think the problem is where the **//Find the middle of the circle** is because when Swift detects `CGPointMake` it will connect the two points? I think, i'm not too sure. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `CGContextAddArc()` documentation:

> If the current path already contains a subpath, Quartz adds a line
>   connecting the current point to the starting point of the arc. If the
>   current path is empty, Quartz creates a new subpath with a
>   starting point set to the starting point of the arc.

Therefore you have to "move to" the initial point of the circle first:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x + CGFloat(cos(startAngle)) * radius, center.y + CGFloat(sin(startAngle)) * radius)
CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, CGFloat(radius), CGFloat(startAngle), CGFloat(endAngle), 0)

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, inside.x + CGFloat(cos(startAngle)) * radius, inside.y + CGFloat(sin(startAngle)) * radius)
CGContextAddArc(context, inside.x, inside.y, CGFloat(radius), CGFloat(startAngle), CGFloat(endAngletwo),0)
```

(You would need less type conversations if you  use `CGFloat` consequently instead of a `Float`/CGFloat` mixture.)

Alternatively use `CGContextAddEllipseInRect()` to draw a full circle.

Comment: what would the parameters be? @Martin

Comment: @user3358638: CGContextAddEllipseInRect() takes a rectangle (CGRect) as parameter and draws an ellipse which "fits" into this rectangle. If the rectangle is a square then you'll get a circle. It is all documented: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextAddEllipseInRect. – Did you try the `CGContextClosePath()` solution?

Comment: I put CGContextClosePath() between CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, CGFloat(radius), CGFloat(startAngle), CGFloat(endAngle), 0) and CGContextAddArc(context, inside.x, inside.y, CGFloat(radius), CGFloat(startAngle), CGFloat(endAngletwo),0)
 And nothing happened. Do I need a parameter? @Martin

Comment: @user3358638: My answer was actually wrong, it have updated (and tested) the code.

Comment: would it be possible to show the circle being drawn? @Martin

Comment: @user3358638: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Like when the page with the circles is opened, the user will see the animation of the circles being drawn. @Martin